# Express framework giving a very strange error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use Express in node, install everything okay, compiled, got npm and installed express with:

> npm install express

The problem is, everytime I try to "require" it, it gives me an error!
Take a look, a simple file app.js as:

```
var express = require('express');
```

When I run it:

```
tlab065:~/proj/Express-server-abstraction> node app.js 
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/people/home/jdomingues/local/node/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/server.js:87:44)    
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:379:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:305:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:271:10)
    at require (module.js:317:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/people/home/jdomingues/local/node/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/index.js:28:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:379:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:305:31
```

Can someone help me? Why am I getting this error? How can I maybe install a different version from express?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that you probably have the latest connect (as opposed to "you need to install the latest connect") the command @Shripad showed is helpful and will probably show you that you have connect 1.0, *yay*...uh oh express isn't quite ready for 1.0 connect, do this to go back to 0.5.10:

```
npm install connect@0.5.10
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error but when I roll back and it shows connect@0.5.10 as active I'm still getting the same error.  This is very new and probably has to do with upgrading earlier today.  It just hasn't fully rolled back for some reason.

Comment: today was whacky...check that you are using express@1.0.7 & connect@0.5.10

Comment: Yeah npm uninstall connect@1.*.* isn't working for me. The files are still in /usr/local/node/lib/connect but I'm scared to start RMing them.

Comment: oh hey you don't need to uninstall, just install the version you want and that will be the active version, that way you can still target specific versions from within an app like so: express = require('express@1.0.7');

Comment: This is an issue with require.paths.. Node checks for express in a directory which still has the old version. I guess latest NPM version stores in a path that has lesser precedence in require.paths.. So even if NPM installs and shows express@1.0.7 as active it isnt used by node. :)

Comment: that makes sense, what happens when you rollback NPM?

Comment: @jpstrikesback Mar 3 at 3:30

> check that you are using express@1.0.7 & connect@0.5.10

Thanks, works for me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the latest connect installed (connect@0.5.10). Make sure you check the connect version that is installed and active:

`npm ls connect | grep active`

The line that throws up an error references connect.Server.

Answer (score 3):

commenting out the code that includes connect helped in my case.

`//connect = require('connect');`

Answer (score 2):

try *jpstrikesback* answer and make sure to install the dependencys in the correct order:

```
npm install connect@0.5.10
npm install express@1.0.7
```

because **npm install express** will install the latest version of connect (if no one is available, and it will break) and in express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/server.js

```
connect = require('connect')
```

which seems to require the latest version of connect not the one you have required in your app.

Comment: installing the dependencies like you suggested did not help in my case. somehow express still installs a newer version of connect and this seems to get used (?!?). to illustrate this here's a snippet of my npm ls: http://tinypic.com/r/z1nxk/6

Answer (score 0):

For others (if your connect@1.0.1 doesn't uninstall with npm uninstall connect@1.0.1) I removed the actual files found at /usr/local/lib/node/connect/

Hope that helps.