# error when trying to require expressjs in a node.js app

Tags: node.js, express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Express framework giving a very strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161828/express-framework-giving-a-very-strange-error)

I'm sure that I'm making a seriously basic mistake in my setup or configuration, but for some reason, whenever I include:

```
require('express');
```

in a file (for instance test.js) and then run that file with:

```
node test.js
```

I get the following error:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/server.js:87:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:272:10)
    at require (module.js:318:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express/index.js:28:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
```

I installed node using homebrew, and I installed express using npm.  Here are the versions of all the players (at least that I'm aware of):

```
node -v
v0.4.1
express -v
1.0.7
npm -v
0.3.11
```

These are all found in /usr/local/bin which is in my path, and I have set $NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node (which appears to be correct, as thats where I see that npm put express).

If I switch my NODE_PATH to /usr/local/bin I seem to get past this, but then get the following error:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createServer'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node/test/app.js:8:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:380:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:306:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:272:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:393:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
```

This is the first question I've ever asked on here, so apologies if I've made some sort of mistake or error, and like I said, I'm sure this is something I've done wrong in setup or configuration as I'm using very simple code directly from expressjs.com.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following question...see here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5161828/149390