# Crytip node.js error

Tags: node.js

```
$ node server.js

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bodyDecoder'
    at HTTPServer.<anonymous> (/home/jrg/Realtime-Demo/settings.js:20:18)
    at HTTPServer.configure (/home/jrg/Realtime-Demo/node_modules/express/lib/http.js:543:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jrg/Realtime-Demo/settings.js:18:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jrg/Realtime-Demo/server.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
```

When I try and run the [Instagram node.js Realtime Demo](https://github.com/Instagram/Realtime-Demo) project. The server is Ubuntu 10.04 (if that makes a difference, which I doubt).

This is not a duplicate of [Express framework giving a very strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161828/express-framework-giving-a-very-strange-error) - I tried the instructions there and they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) and [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware) has `bodyParser` middleware, but not `bodyDecoder`.

It was renamed in the 1.0.0 version of the connect. It's a reason, why node.js projects must have `package.json` descriptor with dependences section, where components versions may be fixed.

You can install 0.5.10 version of connect or try to replace `bodyDecoder` with `bodyParser`