# Nodejs / Express 'prototype' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following error while trying to start my node app:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Full error:

```
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/express/lib/express/server.js:87:44)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
    at require (module.js:368:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/express/lib/express/index.js:28:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
```

I have noted this previous question on the same error: [Express framework giving a very strange error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161828/express-framework-giving-a-very-strange-error). I tried to install the older version of connect, but this did not work and I received the same error.

Node version: v0.5.9-pre

Comment: try an earlier version of node?

Comment: @JasonMiesionczek, I have just downgraded to nodejs v 0.0.4 but still no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: have you tried this: `npm install connect@0.5.10
npm install express@1.0.7`

Comment: I have just tried that. Seemed to fix the prototype error, thanks! But has caused this error: 'TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bodyParser''

Comment: What did you do differently after it was working initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by starting from scratch and re-installing node again with an older version 0.4.8.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments on your question, could you post the code you are using? you are most likely missing an `app.use` statement

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing some dependencies.  Add a package.json file to the root of your project directory

```
{
    "name": "myproject"
  , "version": "0.0.1"
  , "private": true
  , "dependencies": {
      "express": "2.4.6"
    , "ejs": ">=0.4.3" 
  }
}
```

Then, run `npm install -d` from the project directory.  If you're using jade instead of ejs, change that line on the package.json to jade and it's current version.